# Creating targets based on routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to solve an issue.

I'm trying to manage an advertising skin on my website using this gem:

[Google_DFP](https://github.com/digineo/google_dfp)

Now I'm using the standard invocation call on the homepage:

```
<%= dfp_tag :skin %>
```

I want to add the skin to the whole website, so in the application layout, using the targeting options to select the pages where the skin appear

```
<%= dfp_tag :leaderboard, { :page => 'Home' } %>
```

I need to set a target for some pages, for example the content type and the the section of my contents. It the right way to use a variable in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea sounds perfectly legitimate. You can set an instance variable in each controller action, or perhaps in a `before_filter` to cover multiple controller actions at once. After the views are compiled from the controller actions they are then yielded into the layout and any instance variables defined in the controller will be referenced when compiling the layout. So, yeah, supply any action-specific behavior via instance variables.